# Referencing elements by 'class' and not 'id'

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am trying to reference elements (to get pieces of text) in a news website and display them in a simple way.

I watched a YouTube tutorial about referencing elements and it referenced paragraphs using 'getElementById.'

The website I want to use doesn't use 'Id=' very much, it mostly uses 'class=' so I cannot use this same method.

I tried swapping the above 'getElementById' for 'getElementsByClassName' however I am getting the answer 'undefined.'

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<p class="para1" > this is the 1st paragraph </p>
<p> <br/> </p>
<p> <br/> </p>
<p> <br/> </p>
<p class="para2" > this is the 2nd paragraph </p>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Check";
input.onclick = showAlert1;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:100px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input);//Placement of check button on website;

function showAlert1()
{
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('para2').innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that getElementById() returns a single element, whereas getElementsByClassName() returns a list of elements (a live HTMLCollection of elements with that class name).

One thing you might need to do is getElementsByClassName()[0], which will give you the first element found with that class name.

Comment: You say: 'reference elements (to get pieces of text) in a news website'. Is this newswebsite on a different domain than yours? Are you trying to do this from within a browser?

Comment: I don't own the domain, I'm using Tampermonkey to edit the said news website. Yes I am doing this from Chrome.

Comment: P.S. the code posted here is notepad++, just simulation for my eventual goal. The coding for the real newswebsite is very long and complex. Is that clear ?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements(like an array). So you need to access those using `indexes` like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("someClass")[0];

//Or if you want to access all
var len = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass").length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
 //access like document.getElementsByClassName("someClass")[i]
}
```

In your case

```
document.getElementsByClassName('para2')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: wow, so easily answered. Thanks a lot man. Yeah works perfectly. Just needed to refer to element in the array. I thought that number in square brackets refered to the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to add the script after html tag.

<div class="increased">hi</div> <!-- first specify the tag-->
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- then call in script-->
var i = 23;
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("increased");
for(var k = 0; k < elems.length; k++) {
elems[k].style.size = '100px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution. Perhaps because I did not explain clearly enough. I can not write the HTML content (I mean content on webpage). I am just writing Tampermonkey script to extract HTML content and make a button at the side of the page that outputs the info as an alert popup when I click it.